# How to use php pages in Joomla?

Tags: php, mysql, joomla3.3

I have 2 php pages, form.php and results.php. The form accepts user data and send to the database with mysql query, the results page retrieves the data for display.

I have installed Joomla as my CMS and it is connected with the database in which the form data is also stored.

How can i use these two pages in joomla?

Answer (score 1):

You are better off developing a component for Joomla as that is the correct way to extend the functionality. Take a look at http://www.component-creator.com it can write all the code for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can place these two pages into your web root directory & those will work.
If you want to use configurations defined for Joomla, just include those files into your PHP files.

Comment: I tried this, but when i open my website, i dont see the pages. I have downloaded jumi to include php files in article, but how do i do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to place your form within a Joomla article, I would suggest using a form builder extension - there are quite a few in the Joomla extensions directory: http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/contacts-and-feedback/forms

Using an extension like this will allow you to create your form in the Joomla admin area, publish it to your site, and then accept submissions which could then be emailed to you or viewed in the admin area.